# installing python2.4 on osx10.6?

Tags: snow-leopard, python

I prefer installing stuff from their source and dont use package managers generally. Has anyone here tried building python2.4 from source here? If so, had any luck with the same?

Comment: I use package managers which build from source to see where the issues are and how they were fixed - so I can just look at the patches from the package manager to see the issues - or for python just get it from python.org

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have some troubles building it from a sources. My 0.02$:

- check here https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/lang/python24

In the `files` subdir you can see the needed patches to sources, but especially the patches needed to the `Makefile` and `configure`, for the successful build. Use the above as a learning material for your own build process.

*Ps: only wondering, what is wrong with macports.org? Why does not use it directly? All things are builded/compiled on your machine from the sources and you can always check the patches and so on... (so, no binary installs).*